# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - Failure to install app on physical device

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, build-error

I develop app in Flutter. It runs smoothly on Android but fails to install on physical  iOS device. However, on iOS simulator no issues.

I know this problem has been raised many time but it seems I tried everything I could find to solve the problem and nothing worked.

Here is a compete info:

PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/alexvolkov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hevcynzojavdthdavzfxqgoijgls/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

cd /Users/alexvolkov/Documents/Apps_Flutter/0-math/App/v_100/_5/test_app/ios
/bin/sh -c /Users/alexvolkov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hevcynzojavdthdavzfxqgoijgls/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh

shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted

chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted

chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted

chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted

chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: Operation not permitted

Standalone embedder initialization failed: Error determining current directory: Operation not permitted

Failed to package /Users/alexvolkov/Documents/Apps_Flutter/0-math/App/v_100/_5/test_app.

**Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code**

I have macOS 11 Big Sur and latest Xcode.

Comment: try `sudo chmod -R 777 /Users/alexvolkov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hevcynzojavdthdavzfxqgoijgls/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a run script with the following command:

```sh
$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase --validate -ai
```

Just replace make sure you wrap it with double quotes "" like this:

```sh
"$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols" --build-phase --validate -ai
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (in 2023 with XCode 14.3), I had a similar issue where I *could* build from outside XCode using "flutter run" or VSCode, but could *not* build directly from XCode -- I got the same exact results you did.

This was apperantly because I needed to grant full disk access to XCode:

1. Go to Menu System Preferences -> Security & Privacy.
2. Under Privacy, select Full Disk Access
3. Switch Xcode to "ON"

Don't ask me how this became a requirement all of a sudden... or how is got switched off... maybe as a result of an XCode update I suppose?